# Is a critical section necessary to set a boolean value?

Tags: java, synchronization

Suppose we have n threads accessing this function, I heard that even though booleans are just a bit flip, the process is not atomic. In this function, does `opening = true` need to wrapped inside a synchronize? `opening` is a member of the class.

```
boolean opening = false;

public void open() {

    synchronized (this) {
        while (numCarsOnBridge != 0 || opening || closing) {
            // Wait if cars on bridge, opening or closing
            try {
                // Wait until all cars have cleared the bridge, until bridge opening
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // By now, no cars will be under the bridge.
    }

    if (!opening) {
        opening = true; // Do we need to wrap this in a synchronize?
        // notifyAll(); // Maybe need to notify everyone that it is opening
        try {
            sleep(60); // pauses the current thread calling this
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        synchronized (this) {
            drawBridgeClosed = false; // drawBridge is opened
            opening = false;
            notifyAll(); // Only notify all when state has fully changed
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, concurrent modifications on a boolean value need to be synchronized, use AtomicBoolean or synchronized constructions.

Also, you can't call notifyAll() without owning a monitor here:

```
if (!opening) {
    opening = true; // Do we need to wrap this in a synchronize?
    // notifyAll(); // Maybe need to notify everyone that it is opening
```

So you already have 2 reasons to wrap it in synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `opening = true` **is** atomic - it just does not generate what is called a *memory barrier*.

You should make `opening` (and `closing` for that matter) `volatile`.

```
volatile boolean opening = false;
```

This will force a memory barrier every time `opening` changes, thus ensuring that any cacheing of the `opening` variable is flushed.

Comment: Volatile only ensures ordering for previous reads and writes. The volatile read (to enter the if-condition) does not create any assurances about the ordering of the subsequent write (inside the if-condition), as such, if we only make `opening` volatile, two threads may still enter the same if-condition before either can reset the flag.

Comment: @KookieMonster - You are correct - I am trying to ensure the code functions as expected (i.e. `opening = true` is visible to other threads). There are indeed other holes the code fails for, especially the race around this action.

Comment: while it's indeed true that setting boolean is in itself an atomic operation, the attention put on volatile rather than on critical sections, in this case, is imho misleading, and this answer might create confusion.

Answer (score 1):

A critical section is necessary. To explain this, we need to think in terms of atomicity. Specifically, we need the read and write operations on the flag (`opening`) to be a single atomic operation (atomic meaning, that they happen in a single, indivisible step).

Consider this simplified example;

```
if (flag) //read
{
      flag = false; //write
      foo(); //arbitrary operation
}
```

In this example, the read happens, and then the write happens afterwards, and anything can happen in between (such as, Thread #2 coming along and seeing `true` before Thread #1 sets the value to `false`, in which case foo() would be called twice).

To fix this, we need to ensure that both the read and write happen in a single step. We can do this by placing both within the same synchronized block;

```
synchronized(monitor)
{ 
   if (flag) //read
   {
      flag= false; //write
      foo(); //some arbitrary operation
   }   
}
```

Since everything within a synchronized block is considered as one great big atomic operation, the read/write are also atomic and thread safety is achieved (so foo will only be called once by a single thread every time the flag is set to true).

---

AtomicBoolean (as mentioned in the other answer) can also be used in this situation, as this class provides operations to read and write in the same step. For example;

```
static AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public void run()
{
   if (flag.getAndSet(false)) //get and then set the flag
   {
      //the flag is now set to 'false'
      //and we will enter this section if it was originally 'true'
      foo();
   }
}
```

As a side note, the "getAndSet" operation is functionally equivalent to something like this;

```
public boolean getAndSet(boolean newVal)
{
   synchronized(this)
   {
      boolean val = oldVal;
      oldVal = newVal;
      return val;
   }
}
```

However it does this in a heavily optimized way so is usually significantly faster than using the synchronized keyword.